# Class delegate method is not being called

Tags: swift, swift3

I have roughly following class structure

```
protocol AppointmentModalDelegate: class {
    func didPressSubmitButton()
}

class AppointmentModalView: UIView {

    weak var delegate: AppointmentModalDelegate?

    let doneButton:UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        return btn
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.setupViews()
        self.setupConstraints()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        self.doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPressDoneButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    func setupConstraints() {
        // Setup View Constraints
    }

    @objc func didPressDoneButton() {
        self.delegate?.didPressSubmitButton()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class AppointmentModal: AppointmentModalDelegate {

    private var rootView:UIView?
    var view:AppointmentModalView?

    init() {
        self.setupViews()
        self.setupConstraints()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        self.view = AppointmentModalView()
        self.view?.delegate = self
    }

    func setupConstraints() {
        // Setup Constraints
    }

    func didPressSubmitButton() {
        print("Did Press Submit Buttom From Delegate")
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have defined the delegate in `AppointmentModalView` and tried to implement it in `AppointmentModal`, I have also defined the delegate value to self, however the `didPressSubmitButton` does not gets triggered in `AppointmentModal` class, what am I missing here?

**UPDATE1:**

This is basically the modal box I am calling it in UIViewController, roughly here is the code I am using it in UIViewController

```
class AppointmentFormVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.submitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPressSubmitButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func didPressSubmitButton() {
        let appointmentModal = AppointmentModal()
        appointmentModal.show()
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does `didPressDoneButton` in `AppointmentModalView` get called when you press the button? If so, what's the value of `delegate` at this point? Is `AppointmentModal` retained by anything else?

Comment: I am calling it inside the another ViewController

Comment: @AshleyMills yes it gets called in `AppointmentModalView` but not in `AppointmentModal`

Comment: Is `func didPressDoneButton()` even called? If that's the case, is it `delegate` nil at that point?

Comment: @Larme it is being called in `AppointmentModalView` but not in `AppointmentModal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`appointmentModal` isn't retained anywhere

```
let appointmentModal = AppointmentModal()
```

it will be released immediately

you need to make `appointmentModal` an instance variable of the class

```
class AppointmentFormVC: UIViewController {

    let appointmentModal = AppointmentModal()

    @objc func didPressSubmitButton() {
        appointmentModal.show()
    }
}
```